# Not able to trigger click event when one polygon atop another

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

First, I apologize for posting so much code but I want to be sure you can see all the affecting logic.

*on edit.  the quick test is simply click AddData and then click the Trim Off button until it says "Spot On".  Now click anywhere on the Map.  Spot On will create a Yellow square on "bare map" but will not paint over the purple blocks.  I need to be able to select those blocks.*

I have added some location data and some buttons so I can demonstrate the issue.

Run the script.

click AddData button.  This will draw 9 polygons in the center of the screen.

Click Fence Off so it says Fence On.  Now click anywhere on the screen that is not on the purple polygons previously drawn.  This will place a Fence tool on the screen.

Stretch the handles of the Fence polygon to encapsulate about half of the purple polygons.  Make the fence 4 or 5 squares larger than the purple polygons.

Now Click the fence button again to turn the fence off.

Note that there is a yellow Mask that covers some of the purple polygons and there are Yellow Mask blocks where the mask is over bare map.

Click the Trim Off button one time.  It should now say Nibble On.
Click on one of the Yellow mask blocks.  It should be removed from the map.
Click on the Mask where is covers the purple polygons.  *Nothing!!  That is a problem.

I want my user to be able to deSelect a Masked block at will.*

Click the Nibble On button.  It should now say Spot On.  Click anywhere on bare map and it should turn Yellow and add another block to the Mask.

*Click on the purple block but no Mask is drawn.  That is the other (same) problem.*

The purpose of the Mask is to identify map areas to either add or remove from an existing area.  Much is not shown here but it works great.  The inability to use the mask over existing drawn data is the only flaw.

I have placed alerts and it is not throwing the click even.  I assume the data polygon is intercepting it but it there a work-around?

```
    <style>
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Find your Qtr minute locator
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.22&amp;libraries=geometry">
    </script>
</head>

<body><!-- Declare the div, make it take up the full document body -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 100%" onclick=""></div>

<div id="floating-panel">

    <input onclick="AddData();" id="divData" type=button value="AddData">
    <input onclick="AddGridOn();" id="divSpot" type=button value="Trim Off">
    <input onclick="DrawGridOn();" id="divFence" type=button value="Fence Off">
    <input onclick="ClearGrid();" id="divMask" type=button value="Clear Mask">

</div>
<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    var marker;
    var idx = 0;
    var streetAddress = '';
    var qtrArray = [];
    var dataLatArray = [];
    var dataLngArray = [];
    var userGridArray = [];
    var Startlatlng = "";
    var llOffset = 0.00416666666667;
    var babyOffset = (llOffset / 2);  // offsets gridSelector 1/2 qtr min
    var drawGridSelectBox = false;

    var noLabels = true;
    var addGridOn = false;
    var drawGridBox = false;
    var deSelectOn = false;
    var gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polygon();
    var gridSelectBox = new google.maps.Polygon();
    var gridUserArea = new google.maps.Polygon();
    var qtrNELatLngCode;
    var qtrSWLatLngCode;

    var gridline;
    var latPolylines = [];
    var lngPolylines = [];
    var lngLabels = [];
    var otherColor = "";
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0, -84.0),
            zoom: 14,
            streetViewControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        });
       loadData();
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
            if (addGridOn) { //spot on
                drawGridBox = true;//yellow box
                createGridBox(event.latLng);
                return;
            }

                if (drawGridSelectBox) createGridSelectBox(event.latLng);
        });


        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
            var sLat = map.getCenter().lat();
            var sLng = map.getCenter().lng();
            createGridLines(map.getBounds());
        });
    }  // initialize

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

    function createGridLines(bounds) {
        for (var i = 0; i < latPolylines.length; i++) {
            latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
        }

        latPolylines = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < lngPolylines.length; j++) {
            lngPolylines[j].setMap(null);
        }
        lngPolylines = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < lngLabels.length; k++) {
            lngLabels[k].setMap(null);
        }
        lngLabels = [];

        if ((map.getZoom() < 12))  {
            return;
        }
        var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
        var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();

        // define the size of the grid
        var topLat = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

        var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
        var leftLong = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

        qtrNELatLngCode = ddToQM(topLat, rightLong);
        qtrSWLatLngCode = ddToQM(bottomLat, leftLong);

        for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) latPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, leftLong), new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, rightLong)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.1,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));
        for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) lngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(topLat, longitude), new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude)],
            map: map,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.1,
            strokeWeight: 1
        }));

        if ((map.getZoom() < 15)|| (noLabels==true)) {
            for (var l = 0; l < lngLabels.length; l++) {
                lngLabels[l].setMap(null);
            }
            lngLabels = [];
            return;
        }  // set lngLabels to null

        for (var x = 0; x < latPolylines.length; ++x) {
            for (var y = 0; y < lngPolylines.length - 1; ++y) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latPolylines[x].getPath().getAt(0).lat(),
                        lngPolylines[y].getPath().getAt(0).lng());

                var qtrLatLng = ddToQM(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng());

                lngLabels.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: latLng,
                    icon: {
                        url: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?"
                        + "chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|"
                        + qtrLatLng
                        + "|FFFFFF|000000",
                        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 42)
                    }
                }));
            }
        }
    }  // end createGridLines

    function createGridSelectBox(point) {
        // places the draggable, editable plumb colored box on the screen to select QtrMinutes


        var bottomLeftLat = (Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset) - babyOffset;
        var bottomLeftLong = (Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset) - babyOffset;

        var gridLineSquare = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //lwr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //upr right
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong)];  //upr left
        //auto-complete to lwr left

        if (drawGridSelectBox == true) {
            gridSelectBox = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: gridLineSquare,
                draggable: true,
                geodesic: true,
                editable: true,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeColor: "#CC0099",
                strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                strokeWeight: 1
            });

            gridSelectBox.setMap(map);
            drawGridSelectBox = false;
        }
    }

    function MarkArea(Lat, Lng, otherColor) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
        drawUserGrids(latLng, otherColor);
    }


    function DrawGridOn() {       //creates plumb GridSelectBox
//Fence On/Off
        if (document.getElementById("divFence").value=="Fence Off"){
            document.getElementById("divFence").value="Fence On";
            drawGridSelectBox = true;
        }
        else
        if (document.getElementById("divFence").value=="Fence On"){
            document.getElementById("divFence").value="Fence Off";
            CreateMask();
            gridSelectBox.setMap(null);
            drawGridSelectBox = false;
        }
        document.getElementById("divSpot").value="Trim Off";
        deSelectOn = false;
        addGridOn = false;
    }



    function CreateMask() {
        for (var xx = 0; xx < latPolylines.length; ++xx) {
            for (var yy = 0; yy < lngPolylines.length - 1; ++yy) {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latPolylines[xx].getPath().getAt(0).lat(),
                        lngPolylines[yy].getPath().getAt(0).lng()); //

                if ((google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng, gridSelectBox))) {
                    createGridBox(latLng);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function GotoLatLng(Lat, Lng) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lat, Lng);
        map.setCenter(latlng);
    }


    function AddGridOn() {   // Allows adding 1 QtrMin Spot On
        if (document.getElementById("divSpot").value=="Trim Off"){
            document.getElementById("divSpot").value="Nibble On";
            addGridOn = false;
            deSelectOn = true;
        }
        else
        if (document.getElementById("divSpot").value=="Nibble On"){
            document.getElementById("divSpot").value="Spot On";
            deSelectOn = false;
            addGridOn = true;
        }
        else
        if (document.getElementById("divSpot").value=="Spot On"){
            document.getElementById("divSpot").value="Trim Off";
            deSelectOn = false;
            addGridOn = false;
        }
        //report status
    }

    function toggleButtons() {
        document.getElementById("divSpot").disabled=!document.getElementById("divSpot").disabled;
        document.getElementById("divFence").disabled=!document.getElementById("divFence").disabled;
        document.getElementById("divMask").disabled=!document.getElementById("divMask").disabled;
    }


    function NoLabelsOn() {
        noLabels = true;
    }

    function NoLabelsOff() {
        noLabels = false;
    }

    function ClearGrid() {
// removes entire yellow mask
        if (qtrArray) {
            for (var i in qtrArray) {
                qtrArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
        qtrArray = [];
        idx = 0;
    }

    function ClearUserGrid() {
        // removes all mapped boxes
        if (userGridArray) {
            for (var i in userGridArray) {
                userGridArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        }
        userGridArray = [];
    }


    function drawUserGrids(point, otherColor) {
        // Square limits
        //  these are QtrMinutes stored in the database and drawn


        var bottomLeftLat = (Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset);
        var bottomLeftLong = (Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset);

        var gridLineSquare = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //lwr right
            new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //upr right
            new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), bottomLeftLong)];  //upr left

            gridUserArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: gridLineSquare,
                draggable: false,
                geodesic: true,
                editable: false,
                fillColor: otherColor,
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeColor: "#CC0099",
                strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                strokeWeight: 1
            });

            gridUserArea.setMap(map);
            userGridArray.push(gridUserArea);
    }

    function createGridBox(point) {
//creates the Yellow grid for New Qtr Minutes
        var arrayIdx = 0;
        var addListenersOnPolygon = function (polygon) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
                if (deSelectOn == true) {
                    arrayIdx = qtrArray.indexOf(polygon);
                    qtrArray.splice(arrayIdx, 1);
                    polygon.setMap(null);
                }
            });
        };

        var bottomLeftLat = (Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset);
        var bottomLeftLong = (Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset);

        var gridLineSquare = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
            new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //lwr right
            new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //upr right
            new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), bottomLeftLong)];  //upr left

        var maskQuarterMin = ddToQM(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong);
        drawGridBox = true;
        if (qtrArray) {
            for (var i in qtrArray) {
                if (qtrArray[i].get("qtrMinute") == maskQuarterMin) {
                    drawGridBox = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (drawGridBox == true) {
            gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polygon({
                path: gridLineSquare,
                draggable: false,
                geodesic: true,
                editable: false,
                fillColor: "#EAED00",  //yellow
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                strokeColor: "#CC0099",
                strokeOpacity: 0.1,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                qtrMinute: maskQuarterMin,
                indexID: ++idx
            });

            gridOverBox.setMap(map);
            addListenersOnPolygon(gridOverBox);
            qtrArray.push(gridOverBox);
        }
    }


    function ddToQM(alat, alng) {
        var latResult, lngResult, dmsResult;

        alat = parseFloat(alat);
        alng = parseFloat(alng);

        latResult = "";
        lngResult = "";

        latResult += getDms(alat);
        lngResult += getDms(alng);

        dmsResult = latResult + lngResult;

        // Return the resultant string.
        return dmsResult;
    }


    function getDms(val) {
        // Required variables
        var valDeg, valMin, valSec, interimResult;
        var qtrMin;
        val = Math.abs(val);

        // ---- Degrees ----
        valDeg = Math.floor(val);
        valMin = Math.floor((val - valDeg) * 60);
        valSec = Math.round((val - valDeg - valMin / 60) * 3600 * 1000) / 1000;

        if (valSec == 60) {
            valMin += 1;
            valSec = 0;
        }
        if (valMin == 60) {
            valMin += 1;
            valSec = 0;
        }
        interimResult = valDeg + "";

        if (valMin < 10) {
            valMin = "0" + valMin;
        }

        interimResult += valMin + "";

        switch (valSec) {
            case  0 :
                qtrMin = "A";
                break;
            case 15 :
                qtrMin = "B";
                break;
            case 30 :
                qtrMin = "C";
                break;
            case 45 :
                qtrMin = "D";
                break;
        }
        interimResult += qtrMin;
        return interimResult;
    }

    function loadData(){
        dataLatArray.push("34.0020833333333");  dataLngArray.push("-84.0020833333333");
        dataLatArray.push("34.0020833333333");  dataLngArray.push("-84.00625");
        dataLatArray.push("34.0020833333333");  dataLngArray.push("-84.0104166666667");
        dataLatArray.push("34.00625");  dataLngArray.push("-84.0020833333333");
        dataLatArray.push("34.00625");  dataLngArray.push("-84.008333333");
        dataLatArray.push("34.00625");  dataLngArray.push("-84.012500000");
        dataLatArray.push("34.0104166666667");  dataLngArray.push("-84.0020833333333");
        dataLatArray.push("34.0104166666667");  dataLngArray.push("-84.00625");
        dataLatArray.push("34.0104166666667");  dataLngArray.push("-84.0104166666667");


    }
   function AddData(){
       var sLat = "";
       var sLng = "";

       for (var i = 0; i < dataLatArray.length; i++) {
           sLat = dataLatArray[i];
           sLng = dataLngArray[i];
           MarkArea(sLat, sLng, "#EE82EE");
       }


    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have a div with id="map-canvas" in your HTML.  (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null`).  Did you test the posted code?

Comment: Once I fix it so it shows a map, it doesn't exhibit the issue (the yellow squares go away when clicked, even when on top of the purple ones) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8xL8263/1/).

Comment: Try giving the yellow polygon a larger zIndex than the purple.

Comment: @geocodezip - there was nothing wrong with my code.  I just ran a comparer and it is identical to what I have in JetBrains.  It runs w/o issue.

I followed your Fiddle.  The problem remains. I will edit the question to insure the test is stated more clearly.

Comment: I set the zIndex for the Mask (yellow polygons) to 9999 and it fixes the Nibble.  I now understand that (never heard of zIndex before today)  
But the Spot feature still does not work. 

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
            if (addGridOn) { 
                drawGridBox = true;//yellow box
                createGridBox(event.latLng);
                return;
            }

            if (drawGridSelectBox) createGridSelectBox(event.latLng);
        });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it all working. It required two solutions. The Nibble was adding the zIndex value. Spotting required I add a listener event to the User data.

```
function drawUserGrids(point, otherColor) {
    // Square limits
    //  these are QtrMinutes stored in the database and drawn
    **var addListenersOnPolygon = function (polygon) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function (event) {
            if (addGridOn) { //spot on
                drawGridBox = true;//yellow box
                createGridBox(event.latLng);
                return;
            }
        });
    };**

    var bottomLeftLat = (Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset);
    var bottomLeftLong = (Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset);

    var gridLineSquare = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
        new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //lwr right
        new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), (bottomLeftLong + llOffset)),  //upr right
        new google.maps.LatLng((bottomLeftLat + llOffset), bottomLeftLong)];  //upr left

    gridUserArea = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: gridLineSquare,
        draggable: false,
        geodesic: true,
        editable: false,
        fillColor: otherColor,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        strokeColor: "#CC0099",
        strokeOpacity: 0.1,
        zIndex : 100,
        strokeWeight: 1
    });

    gridUserArea.setMap(map);
    **addListenersOnPolygon(gridUserArea);**
    userGridArray.push(gridUserArea);
}
```